# How to find coordinates of opposite vertices in a boundingbox

Tags: python

I have two sets of coordinates (in WGS84) which describes a rectangle
ontop a map (openstreetmap). The coordinates in this box are the bottom-left vertice and the top-right vertice.

**Coordinates:**

```
                LATITUDE    LONGITUDE
bottom-left:    53.869605   9.3191648
top-right:      69.4197068  29.7990631
```

However I need to find out the correct coordinates on the opposite
vertices, top-left and bottom-right.
The naive approach I took initially (knowing nothing about this) was
to simply swap the lat,lon coordinates as one might do in a regular 2d plane.

**To get this:**

```
                LATITUDE    LONGITUDE       
top-left:       69.4197068  9.3191648
bottom-right:   53.869605   29.7990631
```

This does not seem to work though, because the new box becomes a bit squashed compared to the original box, which I figured ought to be due to the curvature of the earth.

So how could I find out these two opposite vertices (top-left, bottom-right)? preferrably in python.

As per comment below here are the images showing whats going on:
If one looks closely you can see that the radar spheres are distorted.

**top-left, bottom-right**
[image: top-left, bottom-right]
**bottom-left, top-right**
[image: bottom-left, top-right]

Comment: could you add some pictures to show what is going on, your approach should work fine

Comment: @IanTurton If these are coordinates then distance between two points with the same latitude and some constant longitudes depends on value of latitude, doesn't it? So after just swapping it wouldn't be a rectangle anymore, would it?

Comment: it was probably not a rectangle before either - hence why I asked for pictures.

Comment: Hi,
Okay the box is really an image, a radar image.
I have updated my initial question with two images
showing bottom-left, top-right and another one with
top-left and bottom-right coordinates.

However I have since realized that the initial coordinates
before swapping the values does indeed also produce a 
slightly distorted image -- so I believe that this question might be invalid since as you pointed out @IanTurton that method ought to work. 

So its probably alot of precision loss going from SWEREF99TM => WGS84, which is the original coordinate format.